How to extract all id values from the cards array in a JSON object using regular expression
I need to extract all id values from the cards array in a JSON object.
I tried the regular expression
"cards":\[\{.*?"id":"([^"]+)"

on the JSON below, but it only matches the first id.
{
  "id": "57cea8c",
  "boardPlugins": [],
  "pluginData": [],
  "cards": [
    {
      "id": "57cea8c",
      "attachments": [],
      "pluginData": []
    },
    {
      "id": "57cea8c",
      "attachments": [],
      "pluginData": []
    },
    {
      "id": "57cea8c",
      "attachments": [],
      "pluginData": []
    },
    {
      "id": "57cea8c",
      "attachments": [],
      "pluginData": []
    }
  ]
} 


If you're dealing with a JSON, why not dealing it with a proper JSON library?

What app code language are you using?

Here is a regex which works on the particular example you included:
/(?<=[\[,]{"id":")[^"]+/g

To explain this regex:

(?<=       ) this is a positive lookbehind expression

{"id":" looks for an id attribute which is the first attribute of an object (eliminates any nested attachment ids)
[\[,] preceded by either a square bracket or a comma (this eliminates the id which is outside the cards array)


[^"]+ match one or more characters which are not a quotation mark
the /g flag at the end means global, so all matches will be returned, not just the first one

What language are you writing in? Because if it’s Javascript (and possibly other languages too), you’d be better off creating a proper object from this JSON and accessing the data that way.
